# Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf on java-9

Tags: java-9, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

Why I am facing the org.pache.cxf issue's even if I am using the same version which apache cxf document mentioned that apache cxf with java 9 supports 3.3.X versions but I am getting errors. Any help would be great to resolve the issue.
Below is my POM file with required dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-jaxb</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/afxlink</sourceRoot>
                <additionalJvmArgs>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</additionalJvmArgs>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>https://test.com/sample.svc?wsdl</wsdl>
                        <!-- <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/ABC.wsdl</wsdl> -->
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Generated Error:

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.3.0:wsdl2java (generate-jaxb) on project tobp:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1
[ERROR] Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\java.exe" --add-exports=jdk.xml.dom/org.w3c.dom.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\cxf-tmp-13521710507515144969\cxf-codegen8120209960104723950.jar C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\cxf-tmp-13521710507515144969\cxf-w2j13650852005823843615args
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```